# How does a user pay a monero node operator via the RPC pay feature?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, rpc, monerujo

The latest monero update gave users the ability to pay monero node operators via the RPC pay to feature. How does a monerujo android app or monero-cli query the monero address of a node operator to pay them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The latest monero update gave users the ability to pay...

Actually this feature was released in v0.15, not the latest release.

> How does...

Instead of me copying verbatim the commit message or each related flag/command, here is the direct link to the commit for which the commit message thoroughly documents the feature: [github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/289937...](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/2899379791b7542e4eb920b5d9d58cf232806937)

Comment: Looks like I was mistaken. Its actually not a way to pay monero node operators directly with monero, but the client using the monero node pays via "mining hashes" which gives you credits on the node. Is this correct? There doesn't seem to be anyway to query a node operators monero address it seems.

Comment: > There doesn't seem to be anyway to query a node operators monero address it seems.  



Well, it is technically there. When your client starts mining for the node operator, it is obtaining the node operators monero address - so it knows where to mine to. It wouldn't be a far step to make it that a client can send monero to that address with an identifier that indicates that the monero should be credited to the users RPC-pay account, but that would require that the client be fine with being tracked / logged by the node operator.